# How can we sort the filter options in the information panel?

Tags: sharepoint-server, filter, document-info-panel

Head scratcher here. I'm wondering how/if we can change the display order of choice options in the filter info pane. Does anyone how to do this, or even better, why this appears to be an order set at random? Currently the column names are sorted [A-Z] in the filters pane, but the choices beneath them are displayed (seemingly) at random.

Below is an example of what is displayed in the filter pane under the column Document Type:

---

[image: Filter pane initial view of column]

---

[image: Expanded view of column choices in filter pane]

---

But, I ordered every choice in the column [A-Z] when I created the column.

---

[image: Choices as entered into column settings]

---

I have tried unpinning the column from the filter pane and then re-pinning. I've changed the column sort to Ascending/Descending by clicking on the column header and then saving the view. Not sure what else to try.

Searching online has not resulted in anything that addresses this issue which surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

It displays in the order of occurrences in the list. The one at the top is the one the most items has tagged.

I believe it is like this because the most used values is more likely something you want to filter on than the ones that are rarely used. I don't think you can change this behaviour in any way.

Comment: That makes sense in a Microsoft sort of way. Would be nice to have an option to choose the sort method.